# Best way to make particle lines on cylinder

Tags: particles, procedural

I have a simple glass cylinder that has particle dots on the inside in line patterns going upwards. They will always start from a specific base line and have a random height.

[image: Glass with particles]

They need to be procedurally generated, since I need to generate random images. What are your thoughts?

Comment: I would use Dupli verts.

Comment: Particles are meant to be random, you want the opposite. I'm not saying it's impossible, but it is cumbersome. If you know Animation Nodes at all this is a fairly simple task. If you haven't played around with vectors or eulers, you might take a while to get used to it though.

Comment: They have to be particles? Or could they be  texture?

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz Thank you for showing me Animation Nodes, I will look more into that. Any recommendations or tutorials that fits my use-case?

Comment: @RobinBetts They have to be random, so if I understand textures correctly, I would get the same order of lines, which is not good.

Comment: @SoroMV Actually if all you want is randomized textures, there are numerous ways to offset textures per-object. World location, object info -> random as vector offset, object input with the same object for all, might be a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a shader approach. I'm not going to illustrate the tree; it's (perhaps unnecessarily?) big, and most of it isn't interesting - it's just plumbing to recover things like cell-centers from a randomized cell-grid.

This though, is the principle that's being followed:

[image]

A 1D Voronoi texture gives us distances from randomly-distributed centers in the U dimension. (stripes, on the left).

Another 1D Voronoi texture gives us stripes in the V dimension in the same way. But this time, the texture is shifted per U-stripe, by adding a multiple of the 'R' of the random-per-stripe *Color* output of the first, U, Voronoi, to the V Voronoi's location in its one dimension. (shifted stripes, center)

The two Voronoi textures are intersected, by considering the U Voronoi and the shifted V Voronoi as the X and Y of a vector, and taking its length.

The *Object Info* node > *Random* output is used as a lookup into a *White Noise* texture to shift the entire space in which these texures are calculated. This gives a random-per-object result.

The linked .blend shows you the tree that does this, and a node group made from it.

The node group has the inputs:

- Object Seed: randomizes the textures on all objects
- X and Y 'Gaps' This modifies the 'Gappiness' - the average space between stripes, and dots-in-stripes.
- X and Y Randomness. The lower these numbers, the more closely the texture approaches a regular grid. Tweaking this  a little can avoid dot-collisions.
- Dot Size
- Y BaseLine.  A margin below which dots will not appear, masked in such a way not to clip any dots. We could add a top margin that works the same way, if needed.

The Outputs are:

- Mask. A mask of the dots, white out of black.
- Distance: the distance of the shading-point from the nearest dot.
- Cell center: the location of the center of the Voronoi cell containing the dot, in the original UV space. A sort of 2D 'Dot ID', could be useful for coloring dots separately, etc.

The group is used in the .blend to produce this:

[image]

If you go for this approach, with Node Wrangler enabled, you could Ctrl-Shift click around the nodes to figure out what the tree is up to.. and maybe improve it :)

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. It gave me a lot of inspiration.